# Sorting a hand of poker

Tags: java

I am trying to sort a hand of poker based on their rank and suits,  but it is still not fully sorted, here are the code, Note  that the suits is sorted, but not the ranks

My hand before the sort:

1: KING of HEARTS
2: FOUR of DIAMONDS
3: SEVEN of CLUBS
4: KING of CLUBS
5: THREE of HEARTS
6: FIVE of DIAMONDS
7: TWO of CLUBS
8: KING of DIAMONDS
9: FOUR of SPADES
10: THREE of DIAMONDS

After the sort:

1: FOUR of SPADES
2: KING of HEARTS
3: THREE of HEARTS
4: TWO of CLUBS
5: KING of CLUBS
6: SEVEN of CLUBS
7: KING of DIAMONDS
8: FIVE of DIAMONDS
9: FOUR of DIAMONDS
10: THREE of DIAMONDS

Card object

```
public int compareTo(Card that)
{
    if(this.suit.ordinal() > that.suit.ordinal())
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(this.suit.ordinal() < that.suit.ordinal()) 
    {
        return -1;
    }       

    int rank1 = (this.rank.ordinal() + 11) % 13; //A>K
    int rank2 = (that.rank.ordinal() + 11) % 13;

    if(rank1 > rank2) return 1;
    if(rank1 < rank2) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Player Object

```
public void tryTest()
{
    Card temp = new Card();
    for(int i=0;i<countCard;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<countCard;j++)
        {
            if(playerHand[i].compareTo(playerHand[j]) > 0)
            {
                temp=this.playerHand[j];
                this.playerHand[j] = this.playerHand[i];
                this.playerHand[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Enum Ranks

```
ACE,
TWO,
THREE,
FOUR,
FIVE,
SIX,
SEVEN,
EIGHT,
NINE,
TEN,
JACK,
QUEEN,
KING;
```

Enum Suits

```
DIAMONDS,
CLUBS,
HEARTS,
SPADES;
```

Comment: `i can sort the hand, but it is still not fully sorted` What does this mean?

Comment: Edited my post to explain more @@

Comment: Can you provide code for enums: suit and rank? I believe there is an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into some standard [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm). The code you have right now compares everything to everything else, and then swaps them if one is greater than the other. However this could lead to you swapping backwards:

1, 2

2>1 therefore swap

2,1

The closest algorithm to what you have would be Bubble Sort, which uses slightly different indexes:

```
for(int i=0;i<countCard;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<countCard -1;j++)
    {
        if(playerHand[j].compareTo(playerHand[j+1]) > 0)
        {
            temp=this.playerHand[j+1];
            this.playerHand[j+1]= this.playerHand[j];
            this.playerHand[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tried this, in the end the my hand have duplicate cards

Comment: @ロクサスRoxasYap double check you didn't mix up a j and a j+1 somewhere

Comment: oh silly me, i really did mised up the j and j+1, thanks for the help, it solved my problem now, thank you !!